# Addition between int option and int

Tags: ocaml

I have an integer matrix of n rows by m cols representing a game board, and have written two functions that allow me to retrieve and set values within the matrix.

```
let get_val board (row, col) = 
  if row < 0 
    || col < 0 
    || (Array.length data) < (row + 1) 
    || (Array.length data.(row)) < (col + 1)
      then None
  else if (board.(row).(col)) = (-1)
    then None
  else Some (board.(row).(col)) ;;

let set_val board (row, col) i = 
  if row < 0 
    || col < 0 
    || (Array.length data) < row+1
    || (Array.length data.(row)) < col+1
    || i < 0
      then invalid_arg "set: invalid arguments"
  else board.(row).(col) <- i;
       board ;;

let board = Array.make_matrix 4 4 ;;
```

All positions are set to -1 initially to represent an empty square. Basically, if I try to retrieve a value outside of the board, I get a None. If the location is valid and not an empty square, I get can retrieve the value at that matrix as a Some type. I would like to increment a position by 1 in a board by using these two functions.

My first attempt in the board by 1 by doing the following:

```
let board = set_val board (2, 2) ((get_val board (2, 2)) + 1)
```

However, I run into the type issue,

```
This expression has type int option but an expression was expected of type int
```

, which I understand is because "get_val" returns a Some type, and 1 is an integer. I also tried:

```
let board = set_val board (2, 2) ((get_val board (2, 2)) + (Some 1))
```

, but board is an integer matrix. The constraints of the problem require me to return a Some/None from "get_val", but I need a way to retrieve the values from the function "get" as an int, not a Some. I've looked into how to convert from an Option to an int, but came up with nothing, since I'm not allowed access to the Option module. I suspect I'm not looking up the correct thing, but have run out of places to look. How would I be able to use the result of "get_val" in a way that I can increment the new value for a position on the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best/idiomatic Ocaml way to do this is using pattern matching.

```
let board = match (S.get grid (row, col)) with 
    | None -> S.set grid (row, col) 1
    | Some v -> S.set grid (row, col) (v+1)
```

Apparently, this way you can strip the `Some` part of the `v` and just get the actual value.

Comment: It would be cleaner to store an int option in the board instead of misusing `-1` as `None`. But if the board is gigantic then memory requirement might make that necessary.

Comment: Naps and shower are the best way to think about problems.